# Упростить решение для нахождения максимального числа-палиндрома полученного умножением двух трехзначных чисел

Tags: python, python-3.x, инспекция-кода

Число-палиндром с обеих сторон (справа налево и слева направо) читается одинаково. Самое большое число-палиндром, полученное умножением двух двузначных чисел – 9009 = 91 × 99.

Найдите самый большой палиндром, полученный умножением двух трехзначных чисел.

```
palindroms = []
for i in range (900,1000):
    for j in range (900,1000):
        c = i*j
        s = str(c)
        if len(s) == 5:
            if (s[0] == s[4]) and (s[1] == s[3]):
                palindroms.append (c)
        if len(s) == 6:
            if (s[0] == s[5]) and (s[4] == s[1]) and (s[2] == s[3]):
                palindroms.append (c)
print (max(palindroms))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Без создания списка и поиска в нем.

```
maximum = 0
for i in range (900,1000):
    for j in range (900,1000):
        c = i*j
        s = str(c)
        s_reversed = s[::-1]
        if s == s_reversed and c > maximum:
            maximum = int(s)
print (maximum)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def is_palindrom(s):
    return str(s) == str(s)[::-1]

n1,n2,max_p = 0,0, 0

for x in range(500, 1000):
    for y in range(500, 1000):
        mult = x * y
        if is_palindrom(mult) and mult > max_p:
            n1,n2,max_p = x,y,mult
print(f"{n1} * {n2} = {max_p}")
```

---

Вывод:

```
913 * 993 = 906609
```

Answer (score 2):

Вариант решения "от обратного" (палиндромов всего 900)

```
def maxpal():
    for i in range(999,99,-1):
        pal = i * 1000 + (i % 10) * 100 + ((i // 10) % 10) * 10 + i // 100
        for d in range(999, 99, -1):
            f = pal // d
            if (f * d == pal) and (1000 > f > 99):
                print(f, d, pal)
                return

maxpal()
```

Answer (score -1):

Я немного сократил правильный ответ

```
max2 = 0
for a in range(999):
    for b in range(999):
        p = str(a*b)
        if p[:: -1] == p and int(p) > max2:
            max2 = int(p)
print(max2)
```

Вывод

```
906609
```

Comment: Не понятно зачем что-то было сокращать. Я вижу что вы изменили параметры range, в итоге код будет выполняться значительно дольше. А так суть кода не изменилась, от того что вы две строки объединили - код лучше не стал.

Comment: Спасибо что объяснили! Впредь так делать не буду